# How to read who created lists on Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I am new to Sharepoint, but I need to get a list of files from my Sharepoint site and determine who created the file. Is there a way to do this? I have been looking online for the last couple of hours and found some Power shell scripts. But when I run them I get errors.

First thing I did was install Microsoft.Online.Sharepoint.Powershell

I ran the script :
`Get-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -ListAvailable | Select Name,Version` 
I got
Name                                   Version

---

Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell 16.0.21909.0

So it looks like I installed it correctly.

I ran the script
 `Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell`
I got the error
Install-Module : The 'Install-Module' command was found in the module 'PowerShellGet', but the module could not be
loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module PowerShellGet'.
At line:1 char:1

- Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Install-Module:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
  ```

Is there something else I need to load ? Or this is the wrong direction to get the information?

Answer (score 0):

You could run the following Powershell commands: `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` then try to run `Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell` again.

For Reference: [Set-ExecutionPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-6).

Comment: Is there any progress on this issue? Comment here if you still need any help.

Comment: Thanks, for your help